# Set up text in a container to word-wrap between spans, but not on spaces inside spans (ideally, using CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to set up a dynamically sizable div, containing spans, each of which contain some arbitrary string, which may include spaces.  If the text in the div is long enough to require word wrapping, I want the line breaks to occur between spans, not inside of them.  For instance, in the below example:

```
<div>
  <span>
    This contains arbitrary text.
  </span>
  <span>
    As does this.
  </span>
  <span>
    Also, this sentence.
  </span>
</div>
```

The line-breaks should occur between "text." and "As"; and "this." and "Also", but not, for example, between "contains" and "arbitrary".  However, I have not been able to accomplish this.

Ideally, this should use only CSS; I would prefer to avoid using JQuery to insert explicit line breaks based on calculations on the width of the div and spans, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by, counterintuitively, putting 'white-space:nowrap' and 'float:left' on the spans, as below:

```
<div>
  <span style="white-space:nowrap;float:left">
    This contains arbitrary text.
  </span>
  <span style="white-space:nowrap;float:left">
    As does this.
  </span>
  <span style="white-space:nowrap;float:left">
    Also, this sentence.
  </span>
</div>
```